# Get rows of first and last datetime records based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df with several columns and can't figure out in Python how to get only the rows with the first and last date/time (columns is in pandas datetime64[ns] Dtype) entry for each id. And also how to create a new df with the datetime difference in days?

Here's a df slice:

| user_id | length | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d8366132199 | 20 | 2021-03-31 17:55:44 |
| d8366132199 | 40 | 2021-05-12 13:55:48 |
| d8366132199 | 10 | 2021-04-09 16:55:47 |
| d8366132199 | 70 | 2021-06-25 17:58:47 |
| d8366132199 | 80 | 2021-06-28 18:55:49 |
| e8172920273 | 10 | 2021-03-28 18:55:44 |
| e8172920273 | 50 | 2021-03-30 18:55:45 |
| e8172920273 | 60 | 2021-05-26 18:55:46 |
| e8172920273 | 90 | 2021-05-26 18:55:47 |

Expected output:

| user_id | length | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d8366132199 | 20 | 2021-03-31 17:55:44 |
| d8366132199 | 80 | 2021-06-28 18:55:49 |
| e8172920273 | 10 | 2021-03-28 18:55:44 |
| e8172920273 | 90 | 2021-05-26 18:55:47 |

New df with datetime difference, expected output:

| user_id | date_diff |
| --- | --- |
| d8366132199 | 276 |
| e8172920273 | 60 |

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `idxmin`/`idxmax` per group, then use the values to slice the original dataset:

```
# get the indices of min/max per group, then flatten as array
idx = df.groupby('user_id')['datetime'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax']).values.ravel()
# array([0, 4, 5, 8])

# slice
df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
        user_id  length            datetime
0  d8366132199       20 2021-03-31 17:55:44
4  d8366132199       80 2021-06-28 18:55:49
5  e8172920273       10 2021-03-28 18:55:44
8  e8172920273       90 2021-05-26 18:55:47
```

Comment: your values.ravel() seems be stack() but dont trust me

Comment: I think they would give the same results in this case, but `.values.ravel()` should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can use `.nth()`

```
ndf = df.sort_values('datetime').groupby('user_id',as_index = False).nth([0,-1])
```

or

```
g = df.groupby('user_id')['datetime']
mins,maxs = g.transform('min'),g.transform('max')

df.loc[df['datetime'].eq(mins) | df['datetime'].eq(maxs)]
```

Output:

```
       user_id  length            datetime
5  e8172920273      10 2021-03-28 18:55:44
0  d8366132199      20 2021-03-31 17:55:44
8  e8172920273      90 2021-05-26 18:55:47
4  d8366132199      80 2021-06-28 18:55:49
```

From there, to answer the second question, you can subtract the last row from the first row.

```
(ndf.groupby('user_id',as_index = False)
 .agg(date_diff = ('datetime',lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).days)))
```

Output:

```
       user_id  date_diff
0  d8366132199         89
1  e8172920273         59
```

Comment: why did you sort is a mystery to me

Comment: also you say nth but there are 3 more things going on, what a style

Comment: and your 2nd answer to their 2nd question doesnt match their output but it doesnt matter for me. in fact, im glad

Comment: The sort was because the question asked for the first and the last date. It is possible that the dates are not pre sorted.

Comment: and the difference for part 2 is in days, because I was unclear what form of measurement the question asked for. This can be changed though if days was not the intended measurement.